# Using -or and -ne for multiple choices

Tags: powershell

This is what I tried and it wouldn't work:

```
If($check1 -ne "1" -or $check1 -ne "2") {
    Write-Warning -WarningAction Inquire "***This is a Finding (O)"
}
```

I ended up using this to get it to work:

```
If($check1 -lt "1" -or $check1 -gt "2") {
    Write-Warning -WarningAction Inquire "***This is a Finding (O)"
}
```

Why won't the first example work?

Comment: What do you have in `$check1` and what's its type? Use `$check1.getType()` to find out.

Comment: '1' and '2' are strings or integers or what? Try to remove double quotes in if operator check1 -lt 1 -or $ check1 -gt  2

Comment: The expression you have written is always true, provided $check1 has a value.

Comment: Don't think in English and then translate to code! :) You translated "I don't want $check1 to be 1 or 2", when you should have come at it as "I don't want $check1 to be 1 AND I don't want $check1 to be 2".

Comment: You want the `if` to be satisfied when `$check` is neither `1` or `2`? `if($check -notin 1,2){...}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first example "wouldn't work" is because (as @Walter Mitty pointed out in the comments) your expression is always `$true` so the statements inside your `if` always run.

To see why, look at the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) below (each column is a part of the calculations in your `if` clause, and each row is the results for a different value of `$check`):

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------------+
| $check | $check -ne "1" | $check -ne "2" | $check -ne "2" -or $check -ne "2" |
+ -------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------------+
|  "0"   |     $true      |     $true      |   $true  -or $true   =>  $true    |
|  "1"   |     $false     |     $true      |   $false -or $true   =>  $true    |
|  "2"   |     $true      |     $false     |   $true  -or $false  =>  $true    |
|  "3"   |     $true      |     $true      |   $true  -or $true   =>  $true    |
+ -------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

One answer would be to use `-and` instead of `or` (also suggested by @Jeff Zeitlin in the comments):

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+------------------------------------+
| $check | $check -ne "1" | $check -ne "2" | $check -ne "2" -and $check -ne "2" |
+ -------+----------------+----------------+------------------------------------+
|  "0"   |     $true      |     $true      |   $true  -and $true   =>  $true    |
|  "1"   |     $false     |     $true      |   $false -and $true   =>  $false   |
|  "2"   |     $true      |     $false     |   $true  -and $false  =>  $false   |
|  "3"   |     $true      |     $true      |   $true  -and $true   =>  $true    |
+ -------+----------------+----------------+------------------------------------+
```

If you want to see why `$check1 -lt "1" -or $check1 -gt "2"` works you could try to build a similar table for that expression and compare it to the two above...